# What is the fastest way to change an HTML5 element position via JS, cloning an element or outputing innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just a hobbyist programmer, please bear with me.

I want to change an HTML5 table row's position in a certain table (let's say, from the 5th position to the 22nd) via plain JavaScript (no JQuery etc.). I see 2 possibilities:

A) copy the element's `innerHTML` and paste it after the 21st row (one can use [range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Range) for that);
B) append the node somewhere else (e.g., `document.getElementById('my-parent-node').appendChild(document.getElementById('my-child-row-node'))` ).

What I want to know is: what is faster for the browser to render, option A (changing an element's `innerHTML`) or option B (appending the existing node somewhere else in the page)? Is there a performance difference at all?

Thank you very much

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the duplicate! I swear I searched for it in google and SO, but couldn'i find it before. I marked it as duplicate for future users that can't find it